# Icomoon and color of text or icons

Tags: css

I have read posts at StackOverflow.

As I understand icons are managed as text.

I. But bullets are inside class where are icon fonts.How to change color of icons not text?
I try to change source but it did not work.

```
src:url('fonts/icomoon.eot?#iefix-ggg507') format('embedded-opentype'),
```

I have bullets like:

```
<li class="icon-checkmark2">
    <b>Text1</strong><b>
    text2
</li>
```

II. How to define style, weight for my text as I have removed source CSS elements like :

```
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
font-variant: normal;
```

but text is still not from body specifications. It seems like style will be ruined when there are icon fonts.

Comment: You can use e.g. Firebug to discover whence the css applied to your element comes from.

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of ways to handle this.

I've grabbed a few examples from the web and posted them in this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZrNPh/).

CSS

```
.holder {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
ul {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 20px auto;
}
.ul1 li {
    color: red;
}
.ul1 li span {
    color: green;
}
.ul2 li {
  list-style-image:url('http://jmcivor.com/icons/akuma2.png');
}
.ul3 li {
    list-style-type: square;
}
.ul4 {
    list-style-type: none;
}
.ul4 li:before {
    content: "4";
    font-family: "webdings";
    color: red;
}
.ul5 li {
    padding-left: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    list-style-type: none;
    border-left: 5px solid green;
}
.ul6 li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.ul6 li:before {
  content: "";
  line-height: 1em;
  width: .5em;
  height: .5em;
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
    margin: .25em .25em 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```